# Create ClearCase View using CAL

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

I'm trying to create a new view in CAL.

I know that I can use the `IClearTool` interface to set up the view via an appropriate command line, but am wondering if there is also a way to do it via the `IClearCase` interface. The documentation suggests that it's not possible, but I'd like to be sure. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I didn't see any obvious way to create a view other than using a cleartool command.
This [old example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=227255) is actually using `IClearCase`... to get `Cleartool`:

```
ClearCase.ClearTool CT = new ClearCase.ClearTool();
string result;
result = CT.CmdExec("mkview -tag " + ViewName + " -stgloc -auto");
```

Comment: Note to self: general links for CAL: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123249